# Angular JS add element to array while inside ng-repeat for a seperate array

Tags: arrays, angularjs

I have 2 arrays in angular. One is populated from a get method and it is iterated through to create a table of inputs

For each row of the input I want to add the value inputted into a second results array. This results array will get posted to a server

I have set up an example on
http://embed.plnkr.co/nVCmukG5abpi1Y4ZHkrq

I'm don't know how to use ng-model to add the input to each row. What I have in my plnkr doesn't allow the user to enter in data into the text box

Thanks for any help

Comment: Maybe it's common, what exactly do you want to set with `ng-model`, I see list of options, and different bottom part depends on selected option type, where do you want to add inputs with `ng-model`?

Answer (score 0):

You should not have to maintain two arrays since in angular we have two binding so the same array will be updated if any of the input box is updated. And then you can post the same array to the server again.

Example Code:

```
$scope.result = [
    {
      label: 'Name',
      value: ''
    }, {
      label: 'Address',
      value: ''
    }
];
```

### HTML

```
<table>
   <tbody ng-repeat="item in result">
     <tr>
       <td>{{item.label}}:</td>
       <td><input type="text" ng-model="item.value"></td> 
     </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: what I'm trying to do is have a table of inputs and only post the values of the rows that were changed, posting the same array works but it includes all the rows that weren't changed